# Prism's DelegateCommand memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, prism

With this code you can reproduce my problem 100% times. I created a 'parent' ViewModel:

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public class ViewModel : BindableBase {

        public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> Items { get; set; }

        public DelegateCommand<ChildViewModel> CloseItem { get; set; }

        public ViewModel() {
            CloseItem = new DelegateCommand<ChildViewModel>(OnItemClose);

            Items = new ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>(new[] {
                new ChildViewModel { Name = "asdf" },
                new ChildViewModel { Name = "zxcv" },
                new ChildViewModel { Name = "qwer" },
                new ChildViewModel { Name = "fdgz" },
                new ChildViewModel { Name = "hgjkghk" }
            });
        }

        private void OnItemClose(ChildViewModel obj) {
            Items.Remove(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Which holds an `ObservableCollection` of `ChildViewModel` instances:

```
using Prism.Mvvm;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public class ChildViewModel : BindableBase {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        protected byte[] leakArr = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 10];

    }
}
```

As you can see I declare a 10mb array in each `ChildViewModel`. Now the view:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="2,3,0,2" />
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" 
                            Margin="10,2,2,2" 
                            Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=DataContext.CloseItem}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="X" />
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Looking at VS2015 memory diagnostic tools I can see that even after every `ChildViewModel` had beed removed from `Items` collection it's still present in memory with one object (for each vm) still holding a reference to it - a `Button` control. What's funny is that if I replace `Button`'s Command declaration to:

```
Click="Button_Click"

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            (DataContext as ViewModel).CloseItem.Execute(((sender as Button).DataContext as ChildViewModel));
        }
```

There's no memory leak - meaning that the debugging tools aren't showing any disposed `ChildViewModel` instances. I don't know if that's a Prism-specific issue, or if it's some kind of a wpf quirk.

I'm using the latest version of both .net and prism library.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if you remove the CommandParameter="{Binding}" part? Does it still exhibit the memory leak?

Comment: No. As I wrote above if I replace Command with ClickEvent it works fine.

Comment: I meant, what if you keep the command but just remove the CommandParameter="{Binding}" part, does it still exhibit the memory leak?

Comment: Without CommandParameter it doesn't exhibit the memory leak.

Comment: CommandParameter="{Binding}" creates a reference from the button to the bound viewmodel, looks like it is being held on to after the item is removed from the collection. Do you really need the CommandParameter="{Binding}" part or could you switch to get the current viewmodel from TabControl.SelectedItem?

Comment: I can do something similar, but I was hoping for a solution for that specific problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I found a solution for this problem (in my app at least) - I stopped binding directly to a `ChildViewModel` instance, and instead I'm binding `CommandParameter` to the `Name` property of `ChildViewModel`. Then, in `ViewModel` I'm just going through Items collection and removing item that has a matching property value. Now VS diagnostic tools are not showing any objects which should have been GCed and weren't and therefore memory leak is gone.

Prism team is analyzing this problem: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/345

Answer (score 2):

Did you check to see if a custom ICommand implementation had the same behavior?

It is possible we introduced this memory leak when we removed the weakreferences because of a related bug.

Could you please report this as an issue here:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues

We will investigate and we will look into it.

EDIT:  I'm happy to hear this wasn't a Prism issue :)

Comment: I didn't check it with a custom `ICommand` implementation. I'll report it tomorrow. Thanks for the answer!